# Mongorestore on AWS EC2 MEAN by Bitnami

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have and issue with mongodb that was preinstalled on MEAN server pre-configuration.

I want to use mongorestore tool to restore my database from local machine on AWS server. As i know so far this tools have an issue (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-620) so i decided to downgrade version on mongo from 3.0 to 2.6. Unfortunately on Bitnami the instalation is pretty strange and i can't unistall mongo in standard way.

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The same problem i have with trying to replace tools with older version:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org-tools
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools=2.6.0
```

System just doesn't recognize this names. Does anyone here have any experience with bitnami mean stack for AWS EC2, and can help me with replacing tools or (the best sollution for me) version of mongo to 2.6?

Thanks
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here.

Bitnami stacks are self contained so you won't be able to use apt-get to downgrade one component.

If you are using a native installer the best you can do is asking for an old version of the mean stack that shipped mongo 2.6.